# Using django-custom-user in existing django-cms project

Tags: django, django-cms, django-custom-user

I have an existing django-cms ver. 3.1.3 project where I would like to replace the default django User model with the one found in [django-custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user) (to have email as user name for my users). I have added the `custom_user` app to my `INSTALLED_APPS` and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'custom_user.EmailUser'`. Finally I applied the migrations.

Everything seems to work fine in my custom models, but the django-cms models that have a reference to the `auth_user` table (`GlobalPagePermission`, `PagePermission,` `PageUser` and `UserSettings`) are not updated to have a foreign-key reference to the new custom user table.

The [django-cms documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/develop/reference/configuration.html#custom-user-requirements) says that is generally advisable to add custom user models in the beginning of a project, but here I am, in the middle of a project, and would very much like to avoid having to delete my cms models (with data) to make it work.

If I were in the beginning of a project, and had added the custom user model before migrating the django-cms models, would the django-cms models actually get a reference to the custom user model table instead of the default one?

Is there any way for me to make migrations for the django-cms models, so they use the new custom user model instead of the default one?

#### UPDATE

Im trying to implement what yakky suggested:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models, migrations
import django.db.models.deletion
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def up(apps, schema_editor):
    PageUser = apps.get_model("cms", "PageUser")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    for pu in PageUser.objects.all():
        pu['emailuser_ptr_id'] = pu['user_ptr_id']
        pu.save()

def down(apps, schema_editor):
    PageUser = apps.get_model("cms", "PageUser")
    db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
    for pu in PageUser.objects.all():
        pu['user_ptr_id'] = pu['emailuser_ptr_id']
        pu.save()

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        (‘myapp’, ‘previous-migration’),
    ]

    operations = [

        migrations.RenameField(
            model_name='PageUser',
            old_name='user_ptr_id',
            new_name='user_ptr_id_old',
        ),

        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='PageUser',
            name='emailuser_ptr_id',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), blank=True),
            preserve_default=True,
        ),

        migrations.RunPython(up, down),

        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='PageUser',
            name='user_ptr_id_old',
        ),
    ]
```

It fails with `KeyError: ('myapp', u'pageuser')` suggesting that it looks for the `PageUser` model in the my custom app and not in the cms app. How do I apply these migrations to the cms models?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about **datamigrations**. For schema migrations you have to create your own migration in the cms. See also Tim Graham on the group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/django-cms-developers/uoJVqR-fduw/-cNhHZqcCgAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313 I managed to make it work. This is what I did:

1. Backed up my database!
2. Created a new app email_username to hold my user model (named User as recommended in the link). A new app was necessary because my main app (myapp) is dependent on django-cms, and if I put my new user model in myapp, django-cms would become dependent on my app - this would create a circular reference.

   ```
   class User(AbstractEmailUser):
       # Needed to add username, first_name and last_name here, because cms.PageUser model depends on these fields
       username = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('username'))
       first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('first_name'))
       last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('last_name'))

       class Meta:
           db_table = 'auth_user' # the model will use the existing auth_user table (at first)
   ```
3. Set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = ‘email_username.User’` in `settings.py`
4. Deleted all migrations of myapp and truncated the `django_migrations` table
5. Ran `manage.py makemigrations` and got

> Cannot resolve bases for [] This can
>   happen if you are inheriting models from an app with migrations (e.g.
>   contrib.auth)  in an app with no migrations; see
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#dependencies
>   for more

... so I removed the `cms` app from `settings.py`, ran `makemigrations` again which now suceeded, then re-added and ran `makemigrations` again.

6. Ran `manage.py migrate --fake`, but got

> Cannot resolve bases for [ModelState: 'djangocms_file.File', ModelState: 'djangocms_video.Video', ModelState: 'djangocms_link.Link', ModelState: 'djangocms_googlemap.GoogleMap', ModelState: 'djangocms_picture.Picture', ModelState: 'djangocms_teaser.Teaser']

... so I removed these apps as well from `settings.py`, ran `migrate --fake`, re-added the apps and `migrate --fake` again.

7. Removed the `db_table` setting from the new User model, ran `makemigrations` followed by `migrate` (without fake!)

Everything now seems to be in order. All foreign keys that previously referenced the standard auth_user table is now referincing the table of my new user model. Existing users have even been transferred because of the db_table trick.

Answer (score 3):

Being said that replacing the Django User model it's not advisable in the middle of a project lifetime (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) as Django does not provide any way to modify the relations after their are being created, to replace the custom user model you can write a custom migration that alter the foreignkey in the django CMS models to point to theand create a new one to the new user model.

Something like:

```
...
migrations.RenameField(
    model_name='globalpagepermission',
    old_name='user',
    new_name='user_old',
),
migrations.AddField(
    model_name='globalpagepermission',
    name='user',
    field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_('user'), blank=True),
    preserve_default=True,
),
migrations.RunPython(copy_data),
migrations.RemoveField(
    model_name='globalpagepermission',
    name='user_old',
),
...
```

Repeat for any relevant model / field.

`copy_data` method will copy the value for the foreign keys from `user_old` to `user`

Code is completely untested but the general idea should work.

Alternatively you can write a RunSQL migration to get the same result.

Users with the same primary keys must exist also for the new model for this to work.

Comment: Prepared a custom migration but how can I migrate a model in an external app such as django-cms?

Comment: Migrations have access to any model, and are not restricted to the models in the current application